# Sound Problem (Reposted from Steam help form)

Tags: sound, games, steam, chromebook

I finally got Garry's mod, (YAY!) but whenever I start up the game, by the time the facepunch logo appears on screen, I hear loud popping noises looping over and over, which is VERY annoying, I can still hear the normal in-game sounds too but with the annoying one's too. I try muting the device and it still does it. I am running Ubuntu 14.04 through crouton on my Chromebook, any help?

Here's the Steam post: http://steamcommunity.com/app/4000/discussions/5/1520386297703572647/?tscn=1507042293

Comment: do you have any other sound problem or only with steam and only with your game ?

Comment: Only that one game does it, no other time it has done this.

Comment: Going out on a lime here but it sounds as if it is game specific then.

Comment: I try muting Ubuntu all together and it still makes the noise

Comment: Still sounds game specific

Comment: huh... ok then.

Comment: Well if everything else works and you have a sound problem only with the game ....